# Cannot activate the Run function in Product menu on Xcode 12

Tags: c++, xcode12

I am very new to coding, above all else =)
So I created new project and a C++ file to work on. After writing my code I tried to run it (cmd+R), but nothing happened. I saw in Product menu that several funcions are actually not active. How could I solve this?

[my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYsnX.png)

I tried to run my code, expecting that the console will allow me to enter a number in order to get the result. Pressing cmd+R didn't activated the console.

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number There is no error stacktrace. He cant click the run icon.,

Comment: You need to press the "no scheme" button to create a scheme

Comment: @AlbinPaul what? They should include their code as text rather than posting an image of the code. Not everybody can view images and/or open links to external sites, and anyhow questions should be selfcontained

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The question is not about the code. Its about the ide.

Comment: this is the code as a text:

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    double usd;
    cin >> usd;
    
    double bgn = usd * 1.79549;
    cout << bgn << endl;
    
    return 0;
    
}

Still, I think it's not a code problem.